# CouchDB 2.3.1 make install fails on RHEL7.6

Tags: erlang, couchdb, rebar

I'm currently trying to install couchDB from source on a RedHat 7.6 machine, and following CouchDB docs install directions:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/unix.html#installation-from-source

I installed the dependencies:

```
sudo yum install autoconf autoconf-archive automake \
    curl-devel erlang-asn1 erlang-erts erlang-eunit gcc-c++ \
    erlang-os_mon erlang-xmerl erlang-erl_interface help2man \
    js-devel-1.8.5 libicu-devel libtool perl-Test-Harness
```

Configure goes fine:

```
# ./configure
==> configuring couchdb in rel/couchdb.config
You have configured Apache CouchDB, time to relax. Relax.
#
```

but I got the following error:

```
# make release
ERROR: Failed to load /usr/local/src/apache-couchdb-2.3.1/rebar.config: {error,{20,file,{error,{badmatch,{error,enoent}},[{erl_eval,expr,3,[]}]}}}
make: *** [couch] ERROR 1
#
```

Actually there is no rebar.config file, but I do not know why it is not created. I've looked around online, but I could not find someone who had encountered the same error.
Does anyone know a solution or a good place to start looking? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW I'm seeing the same issue here: https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/538948787/log.txt on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Taur)

Comment: Seeing this on amazon Linux 2 as well :-/